# Counting sql row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query (I am using SQL Server Management Studio) and C# for development.

The code works perfectly. But I just want to count the number of rows affected.

I have tried several steps of count etc. But it didn't work.

```
SELECT     
   LevelDetails.App_ID, LevelDetails.Intro_ID, LevelDetails.Side, 
   LevelDetails.SLevel, 
   Top_up_details.topupdate, Top_up_details.Recharge_epin, 
   Top_up_details.epin, Top_up_details.app_id AS Expr1
FROM
   LevelDetails 
INNER JOIN
   Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id
WHERE     
   (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '1001')
```

Comment: Can you use a COUNT(*) with the SELECT

Comment: The query you mentioned wil not affect any row, it will return a data table. What do you mean by `affect` here?

Comment: By select you are selecting records so there is no affect on the data.  Either you can get count from db by select or you can count number of records returned.

Comment: @user3133175 with your `query` mentioned in your `question` which gives correct results to a `DataTable`, why don't you use `dt.Rows.Count` to get total count?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM LevelDetails INNER JOIN Top_up_details 
                  ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id
WHERE     (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '1001')
```

Comment: Thanks code works in sql management stdio.. but same come gives error when i am trying to implement in C# this is my code :  

    dtc = g1.return_dt("SELECT count(*) as app_c FROM LevelDetails INNER JOIN Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id WHERE (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '" + Session["appid"] + "')");
    
                    if (dtc.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
    
                        Session["app_count"] = dt.Rows[0]["app_c"].ToString();
    
    
    
                    }

Comment: @user3133175:- What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: @user3133175 with your `query` mentioned in your `question` which gives correct results to a `DataTable`, why don't you use `dt.Rows.Count` to get total count?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this.

You can add `COUNT(LevelDetails.App_ID) OVER() As rowcount` along with the select portion which gives you the total row count .

```
SELECT     
   LevelDetails.App_ID, LevelDetails.Intro_ID, LevelDetails.Side, 
   LevelDetails.SLevel, 
   Top_up_details.topupdate, Top_up_details.Recharge_epin, 
   Top_up_details.epin, Top_up_details.app_id AS Expr1,
   COUNT(LevelDetails.App_ID) OVER() As rowcount // gives you the total count also
FROM
   LevelDetails 
INNER JOIN
   Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id
WHERE     
   (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '1001')
```

Answer (score 0):

@OP this is your code taken from comment.

```
dtc = g1.return_dt("SELECT count(*) as app_c FROM LevelDetails 
                    INNER JOIN Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id 
                    WHERE (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '" + Session["appid"] + "')"); 

if (dtc.Rows.Count > 0) 
{ 
      Session["app_count"] = dt.Rows[0]["app_c"].ToString(); 
}
```

I think in the above code you are missing `Session["appid"].ToString()`, but it is good to check for `null` prior to applying `ToString()`. Here is example:

```
 if(Session["appid"] != null)
 {
      dtc = g1.return_dt("SELECT count(*) as app_c FROM LevelDetails 
                    INNER JOIN Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id 
                    WHERE (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '" + Session["appid"].ToString() + "')"); 

      if (dtc.Rows.Count > 0) 
      { 
               Session["app_count"] = dt.Rows[0]["app_c"].ToString(); 
      }
 }
```

**Another Solution**:

Assuming you are getting `DataTable` that is `dtc` **Using query mentioned in Question** then simply you have to check number of rows returned in the table:

```
string sQuery = @" SELECT     
                       LevelDetails.App_ID, LevelDetails.Intro_ID, LevelDetails.Side, 
                       LevelDetails.SLevel, Top_up_details.topupdate, 
                       Top_up_details.Recharge_epin, Top_up_details.epin, 
                       Top_up_details.app_id AS Expr1
                   FROM
                       LevelDetails 
                   INNER JOIN
                       Top_up_details ON LevelDetails.App_ID = Top_up_details.app_id
                   WHERE     
                       (LevelDetails.Intro_ID = '1001')";

DataTable dtc = g1.return_dt(sQuery);
int iTotalRows = dtc.Rows.Count;
```

Otherwise for getting count from database you can use `sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar()`